# Cyberbullying means bullying that "takes" place using electronic technology

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I don't know why the need to use 'takes" and not "take"? Can somebody tell me why??

Comment: Because _takes_ is the third person singular of the verb! Bullying takes place. The cat sits on the mat.

Comment: Because ***bullying*** is a ***singular*** noun. Usually thought of as an "uncountable noun", so you won't often encounter the plural ***bullyings*** (which my spell-checker underlines as "probably a mistake").

Answer (score 1):

English verbs have singular and plural forms. The third person singular form of the verb 'to take' is 'takes' - he takes, she takes, it takes. We use the singular form when talking about one single thing or person. Bullying when discussed as a subject is a singular noun.

[Subject - verb agreement](https://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp)